# Delete directories in specific path using wild cards

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder in a specific path which contains the same format but always having different 4 digit numbers. Also this file can be found in different drive accordingly.

The folder can be found in "C:\Updates" path but containing the name "L0001234.Me"

the digits 1234 can always be different but have to be 4 digits.

I did the below batch but something is not working right. Would it be possible to help please?

```
@echo off
FOR %%I IN (C E) DO (
    for /D %J in ("%%I:\*") do @del "%J\T000*"
    GOTO END
)
:END
EXIT
```

Comment: *"Something is not working right."* This is a terrible error description, please be specific! Your description says "**L**0001234.Me", but your code contains "**T**000*" -- is this a typo?

Comment: Perhaps, `@FOR %%I IN (C E)DO @FOR /D %%J IN ("%%I:\Updates\L000*.Me")DO @RD /S/Q "%%J">Nul 2>&1`. Please note however that this specifically removes a directory named using the given wildcard mask in a top level directory named `Updates` in either of the two drives. It doesn't search each drive for any directories matching the wildcard mask anywhere on those drives. If that was your intention, you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55417693/edit) to better clarify your task.

Answer (score 0):

You can try, using `forfiles`:

```
forfiles /M L000* /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE echo @path"
```

Once you know you get the right directory names, just replace `echo` by `rmdir`.

Comment: For multiple drives you still need a for or multiple commands, I'd also include `/P "X:\Updates`